# No spreadsheets found when using AppIdentityService to authenticate

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-sheets-api

I can successfully authenticate my app engine app using `AppIdentityService`. However when I perform a `SpreadsheetService.getEntries` I receive no entries.

Here's my code:

```
SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Spreadsheet editing");
String[] SCOPESArray = { "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds" };
final List SCOPES = Arrays.asList(SCOPESArray);
AppIdentityService appIdentity = AppIdentityServiceFactory.getAppIdentityService();
AppIdentityService.GetAccessTokenResult accessToken = appIdentity.getAccessToken(SCOPES);

Credential creds = new Credential(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod());
creds.setAccessToken(accessToken.getAccessToken());    
service.setOAuth2Credentials(creds);

SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(new URL("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full"), SpreadsheetFeed.class);

List spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();
```

At this point, spreadsheets is an empty List.

I have shared a spreadsheet with my app by entering the service account email in the spreadsheet's "share" box - this is the email in the form: `xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com`.

Have I misunderstood permissions here? Is "sharing" a spreadsheet with the service account not enough to make the service account "see" the spreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment I believe `AppIdentity` is not supported when updating using the Sheets API from Google App Engine.

It appears possible to authenticate, but the list of `SpreadsheetEntry`s is always empty.

Instead, use the service account from Google App Engine by specifying the credentials in a `GoogleCredential` instance:

```
GoogleCredential creds = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
    .setTransport(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport())
    .setJsonFactory(JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance())
    .setServiceAccountId(serviceAccountEmailAddress)
    .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(p12FileFromCredentials)
    .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
    .build();


service.setOAuth2Credentials(creds);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the sharing to not work very well on Google Docs, i.e. the "Shared with me" folder was rather incomplete. This seems to have improved with Drive, but the Spreadsheet API is ancient...

What I do is share folders containing the spreadsheets with the App Engine service account, and use the Drive API to list the spreadsheets in these folders. The folders are accessed with their key. This allows me to configure different folders for unit testing, testing and production.

Here's some sample code for getting spreadsheets from a folder:

```
public enum MimeType { //
  SPREADSHEET ("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet"),
  EXCEL ("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

  private String type;
  MimeType(String type) {this.type = type;}

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }
}

/**
 * Get a list of files of a given type from a folder 
 * 
 * @param folderId The Id of the folder
 * @param type The mime type of the files
 * @return a {@link FileList} containing the desired files
 * @throws IOException
 */
public FileList getFolderItems(String folderId, MimeType type) throws IOException {
    QueryBuilder query = new QueryBuilder();
    query.addParent(folderId).setMimeType(type);
    FileList list = drive.files().list().setQ(query.getQuery()).execute();
    return list;
}
```

You can then use `File.getId()` to retrieve the file key to use with the Spreadsheet API.

As an aside, I recommend against using the spreadsheet API from App Engine. The API constantly runs into timeouts and other exceptions when called from GAE. I had to move my processing into a queued task which unfortunately doesn't have the longer URLFetch timeouts as promised (see [issue 10470](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10470)), but at least, the requests are not canceled.

I wrote wrapper around most Spreadsheet API calls to retry the call when getting an exception. And I am constantly adding more wrappers.

Comment: Thanks, but I still wasn't able to get this to work with AppIdentity. In the end, switching to using the named service account with `GoogleCredential` is what worked.

Comment: I use the same sequence of commands to work with the spreadsheet API with AppIdentity. Did you try any other command using a given file key in the API? My Drive connection was built with a different credential using `AppIdentityCredential.Builder`

Comment: Hello Alex,   

Thanks for your info, indeed its better to use the Drive API where possible.
One question; how do you retrieve the Spreadsheet with File.getId()?
Do you have an example?

Regards,

Roland

Comment: @Roland Beuker I use `urlFactory.getWorksheetFeedUrl(file.getId(), "private", "full")` (or any other feed url builder). `file.getId()` returns the spreadsheet key

Comment: @Alex  

With some debugging i found out:`String lSpreadsheetFileId = pSpreadsheetFile.getId();
        String lSpreadsheetUrlString = String.format("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/%s", lSpreadsheetFileId);
URL lSpreadsheetUrl = new URL(lSpreadsheetUrlString);
SpreadsheetEntry lSpreadsheetEntry = = mSpreadsheetService.getEntry(lSpreadsheetUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);`
But how do you use your WorksheetFeedUrl to get a SpreadsheetEntry?

Comment: @Roland Beuker I don't; what should I do with a SpreadhsheetEntry? All it can do is give me worksheets. Which I fetch from the WorksheetFeed.

Comment: I created a library with the possibility to work with the SpreadsheetService and GoogleDrive files. With the above solution the only difference is the way i get my SpreadsheetEntry. From this top level class all the code is generic ... I also like the SpreadsheetEntry as it models one spreadsheet what it actually is in the real world.

Comment: @Roland Beuker Post a question and I can add some example code.

Comment: @Alex thanks, here's my question link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863845/official-google-spreadsheet-drive-usage