# Official Google Spreadsheet/Drive usage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

The Google SpreadsheetService seems a 'work in progress' with sometimes/suddenly slow answers, random error messages etc. As some people already suggest i'm using the Google Drive API where possible when working with the Spreadsheet API. But i couldn't find decent documentation about the Google Drive/Spreadsheet API mix.

With some debugging and trial/error i created an 'entrypoint' at the level of `SpreadsheetEntry`:

```
String lSpreadsheetFileId = pSpreadsheetFile.getId(); 
String lSpreadsheetUrlString = String.format("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/%s", lSpreadsheetFileId); 
URL lSpreadsheetUrl = new URL(lSpreadsheetUrlString); 
SpreadsheetEntry lSpreadsheetEntry = mSpreadsheetService.getEntry(lSpreadsheetUrl, SpreadsheetEntry.class);
```

Now i can start with a query on the SpreadsheetService or with a Google Drive File. Both deliver a `SpreadsheetEntry`. From this point the code is equal for both situations.

This works, but is is my own Google hacking solution which could break with an update on the interface. I saw some posts with more 'official' methods:

```
urlFactory.getWorksheetFeedUrl(file.getId(), "private", "full"); // (or any other feed url builder). file.getId()
```

What is the official 'by design' way to use Google Drive files with Google Spreadsheet?

Can i get some real code examples (more than; "just use the feed" etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to stack questions starting with What is the best way to X are opinion based or to broad.  We also don't supply code examples.    If you are having a problem with your code we can help with that but by the looks of it your code is working.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes the code is working (now), but i'm looking for the actually 'designed' solutions by Google instead of my own hacking.

Comment: Google Sheets is old gdata API Google would rather you use app scripts instead that is why you wont find any documentation or tutorials on how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Spreadsheet Service is already deprecated. Use [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) instead on your implementation on integrating Google Drive and Spreadsheet. Using the Apps Script API, you can almost implement most of the Google Apps integration in your application.

Comment: Where did you get the info that it is deprecated? The [Sheets API Page](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/) just says that the Scripts API is more powerful. I still hope for a reals Sheets API; with the Scripts API I would have to implement proxy scripts for all simple tasks such as reading a couple of cells...

Comment: @AlexR **We are also deprecating the non-current versions of the Spreadsheets, Contacts, Documents List and Freebase APIs** https://developers.googleblog.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html

Comment: That should refer to (non-current) versions 1 and 2, not the current version 3 (see the [version overview](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#which_version_of_the_api_should_be_used))

Comment: @Alex indeed a real client API for spreadsheet seems better than a script wrapper... Is Google dumping Java for this script language?

Comment: @SwagBomb....can u please provide latest working sample on google sheets with iOS objective-c

Comment: @RolandBeuker...can u post here the procedure how to use real client API for Spread sheet

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a `SpreadsheetEntry`, you have to sift through the `SpreadsheetFeed` and look for the key. You can implement a title query to reduce the number of spreadsheets to examine:

```
    SpreadsheetQuery spreadsheetQuery 
    = new SpreadsheetQuery(urlFactory.getSpreadsheetsFeedUrl());
    spreadsheetQuery.setTitleQuery(spreadsheet);
    SpreadsheetFeed spreadsheetFeed = myService.query(spreadsheetQuery, SpreadsheetFeed.class);
```

There doesn't seem to be a query for the key.
However, there is hardly a functionality that requires a SpreadsheetEntry and cannot be done with Drive API or lower level feeds (Worksheed, List, or CellFeed)